# Unable to activate wireless card on Vostro 3360 running 13.04

Tags: wireless, dell

I have a new install of 13.04 and have been working for three days to get the wireless working.

I have tried at least 20 different methods to fix the issue and I have had no luck.

My ethernet works fine after a wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-2_amd64.deb install, but it does not fix my wireless issue.

Does anyone have any ideas or experience to share with me?

Comment: Please tell us more about your cards: lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280

Comment: This is the information I gained from the command chili555 asked I use:                                                                                                                     aaron@aaron-Vostro-3360:~$ lspci -nn | grep -e 0200 -e 0280
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)                                                               I have downloaded and installed the broadcom driver, but I have not worked on the Qualcomm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to correct your wireless, hook up the ethernet temporarily and do:

```
sudo dpkg -P  wireless-bcm43142-dkms
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

After a reboot, your wireless should be working.

Comment: Thanks chili555.  So I had to uninstall wireless-bcm431412-dkms and install bcmwl-kernel-source.  Can you explain why that fixed the problem.  I just want to understand it better.

Comment: wireless-bcm431412-dkms is a patched version that was actually built for Ubuntu 12.10. As you noted in your original question, it doesn't actually work with 13.04! On the other hand, the latest bcmwl-kernel-source built for 13.04 does drive your device correctly as I'm sure you've seen.